# Is it ok to put computation in the body of the for loop?

Tags: python, performance, counter

I want to make sure that `d1-d2` does not recompute at each iteration at the first example. How can I check this?

```
>>> def f(d1: Counter, d2: Counter):
...     for reason, count in (d1 - d2).items():
...         print(reason, count)
...
>>> def f2(d1: Counter, d2: Counter):
...     diff = (d1 - d2).items()
...     for reason, count in diff:
...         print(reason, count)
```

Any suggestions which way is more pythonic in terms of readability and performance?

Comment: it is not recomputed, the first case is ok

Comment: They are equivalent, modulo a temporary variable. Which one you choose is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a for loop evaluate its argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439578/how-does-a-for-loop-evaluate-its-argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments already explained that it does not matter. You also ask "how to check" that `d1 - d2` is not evaluated twice, which is fairly simple by defining a function that prints something.

```
def foo():
    print('foo')
    return range(5)

for n in foo():
    pass
```

This outputs `foo` once, which proves that `foo()` is called/evaluated exactly once (and not 5 times).

Comment: Can we generalize and say that the Python's for loop works in that way that expression after `in` is exercised only once?

Comment: @dandan it's not a generalization. It's exactly the same statement.