# what if we use some math operations inside the range in for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, optimization, range

I am wondering, if we use

```py
for n in range(500/2):
```

does it mean, that for each iteration, it each time solves 500/2 = 250?
Or it just solves it once, and then uses it?

Or

```py
x = 100
for n in range(x):
```

does it mean, that for each iteration, it each time refers to x
Or it just takes its value once, and uses later on?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35439578/7867968) answers your question?

Answer (score 4):

The expression inside the `range()` call is evaluated once and a `range` object is constructed. Then, you iterate over it, regardless of how it was constructed.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick and detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

It is calculated only once, `range()` returns a sequence of numbers (once) which is used for iterating.

More about `range()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) for example.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything is clear now!